# Does ehcache 3.8 allow searching by anything other than key

Tags: java, ehcache, ehcache-3

I use Ehcache 3.8 to store elements, they are keyed by their id, but I would also like to be able to search by their name.

For Ehcache 2.8 there is documentation about how to do this - https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/apis/search.html but I cant find anything for Ehcache 3.8, have they just removed it or simply not documented it ?

Answer (score -1):

Ehcache 3.x does not have a search feature.

If you need multiple mappings for your entries, you can simply add them with the different key / search term to one or more caches.

Comment: So I have to duplicate the key and the element so that will take way more disk space. Ive never comes across a product that seems  to degrade itself between versions rather than improve the product, maybe I need to swap to 2.8 or a different product !